# Select2 - filtering special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a problem with select2 plugin. When I use filter and type "mąka", it finds all the options with "mąka" and "maka" word. Is it possible to customize this script to find just the "mąka" word?

[Preview here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd6Wf.png)

Sorry for my english ;p

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get data via ajax?

Comment: No, I load it from controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From select2 site https://select2.github.io/examples.html#matcher

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/alaniex/c3Ls1uf3/1/

```
function matchStart (term, text) {
  if (text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()) == 0) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

$.fn.select2.amd.require(['select2/compat/matcher'], function (oldMatcher) {
  $(".js-example-matcher-start").select2({
    matcher: oldMatcher(matchStart)
  })
});
```

Comment: Did you check this solution?

Comment: Yes but it don't work with "ą" char ;/

"ł", "ś" etc. it's good but "ą" don't work

Comment: Ok it works! In my view i rewrite this function in other script. Now it works with all characters ;) Thanks a lot ;)