# jquery Select2 - filtering special characters

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using Selec2 to filter the fields in my table and it works perfectly. But
I have a problem when filtering out words with special characters like:
"ç"
"ã"
"õ"

When I type "navegaç" comes to my Servlet the String "navegaÃ§" like the image below.

[image]

[image]

is there any kind of setting of select2 to change charset?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43000164/select2-filtering-special-characters

Comment: Thank you! but this anwser not work for me.

Comment: @20Comer answer should solve the problem for you. Also for server side sometimes default processing is `UTF-8` so you may not need the decoding, but it depends on which framework you are using on Java side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ajax call you need use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode before sending it to server.

```
$('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
      ajax: {
        url : 'Controller',
        cache: false,
        data: function (params) {
          var query = {
            search      : encodeURIComponent(params.term),
            type        : 'public' 
          };
          return query;
        }
    }
});
```

And in server you need decode this characters to UTF-8.

```
String search = request.getParameter("search"); 
search = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(search , "UTF-8");
```